# How can I sample from a subset of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select a random row from a `pandas` `DataFrame` between the 0th row and the length - 100?

Something like `start_state = self.market_data.sample(1)`, except that chooses from ANY row (even the last 100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions.

If need filter first 100 rows:

```
self.market_data.iloc[:100].sample(1)
```

Or [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
self.market_data.head(100).sample(1)
```

---

If want filter all data without last 100 rows:

```
self.market_data.iloc[:-100].sample(1)
```

Comment: The first one will do all EXCEPT the last 100, right? And the second one will only look within the first 100?

Comment: @anky_91 - Are you sure? All rows without N rows?

Comment: @anky_91 - Sorry, then reopening is a bit problematic,but I upvote your solution.